# How can I get tormysql to do inserts?

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, web-scraping

I think my understanding of the control flow here is flawed. What I want is to scrape a bunch of URLs, and as I encounter them, spin up a connection from the pool to insert the URL to my database.

I think the issue here is my understanding of yield. How can I make tormysql accept a parameter and use a connection asynchronously to write that parameter to a database?

Basically, I just want insert_to_db() to insert, asynchronously, a URL to my database. But insert_to_db() is not actually running.

```
from lxml import html
import tormysql
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
import sys
import csv
from shutil import copyfile

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



pool = tormysql.ConnectionPool(
    max_connections = 20, #max open connections
    idle_seconds = 7200, #conntion idle timeout time, 0 is not timeout
    wait_connection_timeout = 3, #wait connection timeout
    host = "unidb.cfavdkskfrrc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user = "#",
    passwd = "#",
    db = "diplomacy_data",
    charset = "utf8"
)

def insert_to_db(game_url):
    print(game_url)
    with (yield pool.Connection()) as conn:
        try:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                yield cursor.execute("INSERT INTO FvA_urls(URL) VALUES('%s')" % game_url)
        except:
            yield conn.rollback()
        else:
            print('committed', game_url)
            yield conn.commit()


username = "#"
password = "#"
login_url = "https://webdiplomacy.net/logon.php"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(login_url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.content.content-follow-on > form > ul > li:nth-child(2) > input[type="text"]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.content.content-follow-on > form > ul > li:nth-child(5) > input[type="password"]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.content.content-follow-on > form > ul > li:nth-child(10) > input').click()

url = "https://webdiplomacy.net/gamelistings.php?"
params = "page-games=1&gamelistType=Finished&searchOn=on"
driver.get(url + params)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > form > li:nth-child(5) > input[type="radio"]:nth-child(6)').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > form > input').click()
# Get all the URLS
page_num = 0
while True:
    page_num += 1
    if page_num % 20 == 0:
        print(page_num)
    a = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[*]/div[6]/div[2]/a')
    if len(a) < 1:
        pool.close()
        exit()
    else:
        for button in a:
            game_url = button.get_attribute('href')
            insert_to_db(game_url)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(3) > img').click()
```

All of the examples of TorMySQL usage I can find anywhere are just repeated asynchronous inserts of 1 to a table. So obviously completely useless.

Is it impossible to have each connection do something independently? Like is this library exclusively only useful for doing precisely the same thing many times asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the '%' syntax for string interpolation is a pattern demonstrated to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Any potentially unsafe values incorporated into the SQL text must be properly escaped.

I also think that including the single quotes is causing invalid SQL syntax to be generated, and the execution of the statement is failing with a syntax error

```
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO FvA_urls(URL) VALUES('%s')" % game_url)
                                                  ^  ^   ^
```

(It's possible that I'm barking up the wrong tree. I haven't verified this with testing. Maybe the single quotes are required or tolerated, and maybe the value is being properly escaped.)

I think a better pattern is to use a comma in place of the percent sign, and pass a tuple as an argument, like this:

```
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO FvA_urls(URL) VALUES( %s )", (game_url,))
                                                  ^  ^  ^ ^        ^^
```

For comparison, take a look at this line of code in `example/pool.py`

```
    cur = yield POOL.execute("SELECT SLEEP(%s)", (t,))
                                               ^ ^ ^^
```

My bet is this where the problem is.

But in the spirit of StackOverflow as a question / answer site, I recognize that these questions were also asked:

Q: Is it impossible to have each connection do something independently?

Q: Like is this library exclusively only useful for doing precisely the same thing many times asynchronously?

Does the code in example/pool.py answer your question? The same SQL statement is being executed with different values, which is what it seems like you are attempting to accomplish.